# How to run 2 files(.py) concurrently and update the variable to another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, parameter-passing, python-multiprocessing

My definite goal is to update the real-time value to Matlab(simulink) from python to apply control system.

With separated processes, I get the real-time updating value.
The value type is an integer.

I want to pass this updating value to Matlab workspace.
So I tried using the command in Matlab workspace : pyrunfile('A.py')

However,
As you see this link, 10th line of "Limitations to Python Support",
https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-python-support.html

Matlab doesn't support multiprocessing.
In other words, if I try to run the python file from Matlab workspace,
it doesn't work.

But multiprocessing is requisite for my work. (not working with multithread)

So my idea :

1. Run the file A.py which contains multiprocessing.
2. under A.py is still running, I pass the desired updating value to another file B.py with loop .
3. Export this value to Matlab workspace.
4. Matlab workspace -> simulink

Firstly , I would like to know whether it sounds feasible or not.
if not, I would like to have some other workflow suggestion.

summary :

python -> matlab  is not possible because of multiprocessing.

python -> ?? -> matlab  , is there any other method?

Comment: To run two files simultaneously, you can use the command line: `python A.py B.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, but you could write the variable to a file and read it from the other file.

```
#Read file
with open("file.txt", "r") as txt_file:
    return txt_file.readlines()

#Open file
txt_file = open("file.txt", "w")
txt_file.write(var)
txt_file.close()
```

You can pass the values like that. I'm not sure how to do the rest, but i hope this helps

Also just make 2 instances of the command line, and run the files seperately to run both of them